# How to handle dynamic Left Boundary (LB) and Right Boundary (RB) in Apache JMeter

Tags: jmeter

How to handle dynamic Left Boundary (LB) and Right Boundary (RB) in JMeter , and if the length of the boundaries are dynamically changing how to handle them in jmeter and loadrunner

Comment: Any feedback on answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of JMeter 3.3, there is not Boundary extractor similar to Load Runner.

It will be available in 3.4 as per:

> https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60213

So you need to use on of those depending on the format of responses:

- For HTML => [CSS/JQuery extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
- For JSON => [JSON extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)
- For XML => [XPATH extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)
- For any format => [Regex Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)